# Spring AMQP and Kotlin - aggregate all the declarations to collection

Tags: kotlin, spring-amqp

How to aggregate all the declarations of queues, exchanges, and bindings to collection in Kotlin?

I have working Java code which return declarations as List:

```
@Bean
public List<Declarable> declaration() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            new Queue("queue-1"),
            new Queue("queue-2"),
            new Queue("queue-3"),
            new Queue("queue-4"),
            new FanoutExchange("fanout-1"),
            new FanoutExchange("fanout-2"));
}
```

But same code on Kotlin doesn't work:

```
@Bean
open fun declaration(): List<Declarable> {
    return Arrays.asList(
            Queue("queue-1"),
            Queue("queue-2"),
            Queue("queue-3"),
            Queue("queue-4"),
            FanoutExchange("fanout-1"),
            FanoutExchange("fanout-2"))
}
```

**UPDATE**

In Java i had Spring version 1.5.9 and in Kotlin 2.1.1.
Since 2.1 `List<Declarable>` is deprecated and use Declarables

```
@Bean
open fun declaration(): Declarables {
    return Declarables(listOf(
            Queue("queue-1"),
            Queue("queue-2"),
            Queue("queue-3"),
            Queue("queue-4")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.1, use `Declarables` to wrap the list instead of a raw list.

Using a `List<Declarable>` is deprecated; it's still supported but you have to set the admin's `declareCollections` property to true.

Comment: Oh, sorry; didn't read the question fully; what version are you using?

Comment: thanks Gary, changing to Declarables fixed problem, so i had different spring version 1.5.9 and 2.1.1